# Display multiple Markers on google map api v3 from $.each loop

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I'm trying to get multiple markers  on a Google map using API V3. 
The marker I want to show is a pink square named beachflag.png. When my program gets to the setMarkers function the values inside  the  arrays created in the $.each loop are lost.  The alert function displays  undefined. I don't see how this is possible because I've declared this arrays at the beginning of the script (global). 
However, when the for loop at the bottom that iterates through  the  location array it has only one value.  All the values I pushed into the arrays(location, lat, and elong) are gone. I have been following an example from google sample api for v3(https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex?hl=fr-FR) and it is not working for me. 
here is my live test page:
 [otakufinder](http://leobee.com/otakufinder/)

```
var userLat="";

var userLong="";

var map;

var eventsLat=[];

var eventsLong=[];

locations=[];

var i=0;

  jQuery(window).ready(function(){

                jQuery("#btnInit").click(initiate_geolocation);

            });

            function initiate_geolocation() {

                //watch position
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_geolocation_query,handle_errors);

            }

            function handle_errors(error)
            {
                switch(error.code)
                {
                    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED: alert("user did not share geolocation data");
                    break;

                    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: alert("could not detect current position");
                    break;

                    case error.TIMEOUT: alert("retrieving position timed out");
                    break;

                    default: alert("unknown error");
                    break;
                }
            }

            function handle_geolocation_query(position){


                userLat=position.coords.latitude;

                userLong=position.coords.longitude;

                var userLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(userLat, userLong);

                var mapOptions = {
                        zoom: 8,
                        center: userLocation,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),mapOptions);


                var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(userLat, userLong),
                title: "Hello Testing",
                clickable: true,
                map: map
                });


             var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)

              $.get('http://leobee.com/otakufinder/scripts/geoloco.php?userLat='+userLat+'&userLong='+userLong+'&randNum='+numRand,



                    function (data){


                        var jsontext = data;

                        var contact = JSON.parse(jsontext);




                        $.each(contact , function() {

                             $('#otakuEvents').append(
                            '<div>'
                            + this.event_name
                            + '</div><div>'
                            + this.lat +"  "+this.elong
                            +
                            '</div>'


                         );// end div
                eventsLat.push(this.lat);

                eventsLong.push(this.elong);

                locations.push(this.event_name);


                });// end .each


setMarkers(map,locations);

function setMarkers(map, locations) {
alert (" in setMarkers function "+ eventsLat[i]);//output undefined
var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/beachflag.png',
new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
new google.maps.Point(0,0),
new google.maps.Point(0, 32));
var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../images/beachflag.png',
new google.maps.Size(37, 32),
new google.maps.Point(0,0),
new google.maps.Point(0, 32));
var shape = {
coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
type: 'poly'
};

for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
alert (" inside for loop "+ eventsLat[i]);// output has only one variable init
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(eventLat[i], eventLong[i]);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatLng,
map: map,
shadow: shadow,
icon: image,
shape: shape,

});
}
}
            }// end data callback

        );// end getJson
 }
```

Comment: example...jqxhr.complete(function(){
for (i=0;i<eventsLat.length;i++){
alert( "lat "+ eventsLat[i]);
var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/beachflag.png',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo there, you are populating `eventsLat[]` and `eventsLong[]` , but you try to access `eventLat[]` and `eventLong[]` here:

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(eventLat[i], eventLong[i]);
```

Comment: I fixed the typo and the problem is still there. the values in the array are not being feed in to the complete function.

Comment: Hi Everyone, I'm struggling to get over the 'asynchronous trap' with this program.
I've done some research and re-constructed part of the code according to jQuery's website. I've uploaded this version to my live test page. http://leobee.com/otakufinder/.  I find it very strange that the complete function alerts success and there is no information loaded. Do I need to put the variables in a hidden input field so that the program has access to the variable's value? I'm not sure what to do next. there wasn't enought room to past the new (typo free) code in the comments.

Comment: Take a look at the last loop in the updated demo, before `alert("second complete");` , you didn't create the markers inside the loop, you create 1 marker after the loop. After the loop i points behind the end of the array, so this single marker cannot be created.